# Comparing Dates and adding days to Dates in a comparison

Tags: java, date

I am totally out of my depth here.  I have this pseudo code that I would like to write in Java but have no idea where to start.  The following is the logic that I would like to express. Any advice would be much appreciated.

```
if(bestBeforeDate <= today() + 2days) // if a product is two days before its best before date
toShipOut = false;
else if (bestBeforeDate >= today >= bbDate- 8 days) // from 8 days before best before day
DiscountedPrice();
else
toShipOut = true;
```

Comment: One way would be use methods from Date() class.

Comment: Seriously, start writing code. It's already very similar to the end result, just look trough the docs to find the exact methods you want.

Comment: One of less fun parts of Java (in my opinion), but not so bad if you are starting from scratch.  See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html

Comment: You could take a look at [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16074398/comparing-dates-in-java/16074453#16074453) and [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18629428/determine-if-current-time-in-java-is-past-a-predetermined-time-by-15mins/18629816#18629816)

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Check Out [Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html).</strike>

Notice the constructor `Date(int year, int month, int date)`

Also notice the boolean method `after(Date when)`

You should be able to find everything you need there.

[GregorionCalendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html) is usually preferred to Date now, but it is the same concept.
`GregorianCalendar(int year, int month, int dayOfMonth)`

`public int compareTo(Calendar anotherCalendar)`

Comment: The constructor you've suggested is deprecated.  Better simply use `Calendar` or even better Joda-Time - IMHO

Comment: This is just my opinion, but you are better off using `Calendar.getInstance()` as it has the ability to provide a localised instance of `Calendar`, unless you have a very particular need to use a particular instance of `Calendar` for specific work

Comment: I assume OP will want a specific Calendar time for the `bestBeforeDate` and will want to use `Calendar.getInstance` for the `today()` method. However, if he is setting the `bestBeforeDate` based off todays date I would agree with you, in which case he should use Malvon's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use *Calendar.add()* to add number of days. You need to have a temporary *Calendar* for each additions.

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(new Date()); // Current date
c.add(Calendar.DATE, 2); // Adding 2 days
```

Comment: Add some discussion about comparing `Date`s and earn some up-votes ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer The very set of examples you posted after my answer points to `Calendar.add()` method. I did not take into the account the fact that the original poster needs help with the _comparison_, which should be obvious.

Answer (score 1):

### Beware of Date/Calendar Classes

Caution: The java.util.Date/Calendar classes bundled with Java are notoriously bad. Instead, use the third-party library [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/), or in Java 8 use the new [JSR 310](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310) features (inspired by Joda-Time).

### Considerations

Think about time as well as date. And time zones. Generally it is best to store and work with [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) time (no time zone offset), then convert to zoned date-time for presentation to user.

### Example Code

I'm not promising this source code example is logically consistent, but it will put you in the right direction. Joda-Time 2.3 on Java 7 on a Mac.

The boolean logic in your pseudo-code is flawed, so I ignored that aspect. I focused on the date-time angle.

```java
// © 2013 Basil Bourque. This source code may be used freely forever by anyone taking full responsibility for doing so.
// import org.joda.time.*;

DateTimeZone denverTimeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Denver" );

// In real world, get 'bestBeforeDate' from storage. Stored in UTC.
// Call 'withTimeAtStartOfDay' method rather than try to set midnight. Not every day in every time zone has a midnight.
// For this example, we'll hard-code bestBeforeDate to first moment of day Nov 1 in Denver. Then convert to UTC.
DateTime bestBeforeDate = new DateTime( 2013, DateTimeConstants.NOVEMBER, 1, 3, 3, denverTimeZone ).withTimeAtStartOfDay().toDateTime( DateTimeZone.UTC );

DateTime now = new DateTime().toDateTime( DateTimeZone.UTC );
DateTime twoDaysFromNow = now.plusDays( 2 );

if ( bestBeforeDate.isBefore( twoDaysFromNow ) ) {
    // Do something
} else {
    // Do something else.
}

System.out.println( "bestBeforeDate: " + bestBeforeDate );
System.out.println( "now: " + now );
System.out.println( "twoDaysFromNow: " + twoDaysFromNow );
```

When run…

```
bestBeforeDate: 2013-11-01T06:00:00.000Z
now: 2013-12-03T04:54:55.405Z
twoDaysFromNow: 2013-12-05T04:54:55.405Z
```